# Should you name all of your UI controls? What naming scheme do you use?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

This can be applied to any language/UI project. When the code is automatically generated, is there a need to name all of the UI controls? Presently I only name the ones I am referencing in code (although admittedly sometimes I get lazy and leave them). Or do you stick with the pre-generated names (textbox1, splitContainer1, menuStrip1, etc..)?

If you name them, how do you prevent overlap such as MyDataGridView1, MyDataGridView2, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always try to set `GenerateMember` to `false` for the controls I don't use in the code, but for the controls I do use in code, I usually choose meaningful names.

For example, if there was a button that submitted something then I would choose `submitBtn`. If there was a username textbox then I would call it `usernameTxt`. Etc, etc.

A small list:

- Buttons: `btn`
- Textboxes: `txt`
- Labels: `lbl`
- Checkboxes: `chk`
- Radio buttons: `rad`
- List boxes: `lst`
- Dialogs: `dlg`

...but above all else, just use what makes sense.

Comment: this is interesting notation, permits to "directly" accede the "good-meaning" member name by the auto-complete. In this case the Hungarian suffix seems to be useless. I use traditionnaly `btnOpen`, `txtName` etc...

Comment: Accepting as answer for reminding me of GenerateMember .. Just wish there was an option to make false the default.

Answer (score 1):

I only name the ones I reference too - most modern IDEs will easily rename a widget later if I need to reference it in code.

I usually give the names some meaning - accountDataView, currentBalanceDataView - it must relate to a concept like submitButton for the button that submits a form.

Answer (score 0):

I name the controls that I access and have experimented with using the "ux" prefix so that I can find them easily with Intellisense.  That way if I can't remember the exact name of a control I know it at lease starts with ux.  Also, if I change the control type, the name can stay the same.  I came across this a while back, but can't seem to find the article about it now.

uxFirstName